# mysql Query to avoid duplicate results

Tags: php, mysql

I have multiple tables as follows:

TABLE 1: **Product**

```
+-----+----------+--------+---------------------+
| id  |   biz_id | name   |    message          |
+-----+----------+--------+---------------------+
| 1   |   1      | test1  | One tow three       |
| 2   |   1      | test1  | One tow three       |
| 3   |   1      | test1  | One tow three       |
| 4   |   2      | test2  | hello world         |
| 5   |   2      | test2  | hello world         |   
+-----+----------+--------+---------------------+
```

TABLE 2: **Images**

```
+-----+----------+--------------+-------------------+
| id  |   biz_id | product_id   |    path           |
+-----+----------+--------------+-------------------+
| 1   |   1      | 1            | img/qwert1.jpg    |
| 2   |   1      | 2            | img/qwert2.jpg    |
| 3   |   1      | 3            | img/qwert3.jpg    |
| 4   |   2      | 4            | img/qwery4.jpg    |
| 5   |   2      | 5            | img/qwert5.jpg    |   
+-----+----------+--------------+-------------------+
```

How can I avoid duplicate in mysql while joining multiple tables?

My Query is Join both tables such that I want to avoid duplicate product(Get Distint product by name) and get all images associated with that product(Eg. Product>name - test1 has images qwert1.jpg, qwert2.jpg, qwert2.jpg )

Comment: What would the desired result look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.name, GROUP_CONCAT(i.path)
  FROM product AS p
  INNER JOIN images AS i ON p.id = i.product_id
  GROUP BY p.name;
```

Please note that this is not standard SQL, but most DBMS offer this functionality (although the keyword may be a bit different).

Answer (score 0):

simple join should do all things

```
select p.name as Name, i.message as IMG from Images 
left join Product p
on i.biz_id=p.biz_id
group by p.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `left join` with `GROUP_CONCAT` or `group by`

```
select p.name name,GROUP_CONCAT(i.path) img 
from Images i left join Product p
on i.biz_id=p.biz_id
group by i.product_id
```